# Apache Spark, Error on sbt/assembly

Tags: apache-spark

I tried to install apache spark on my local Linux Mint but when I do

sbt assembly

I got error like below :

[image]

How to fix this?

Please advise

Comment: Why do you use `sbt assembly` to use Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your picture which is spark binary folder.

This mean you don't need to install that just use it by running bin/spark-shell, bin/spark-submit.

If you want to compile it need to download the source code [image]

Comment: I have run bin/spark-shell on my spark folder but I got error like below:

cst@cst-Ideapad-Z460 ~/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 $ bin/spark-shell
/home/cst/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21//bin/java: No such file or directory


I have java installed:

cst@cst-Ideapad-Z460 ~/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-0ubuntu0.14.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)

What should I do? Please advise

Comment: you need to set JAVA_HOME.